# How to prove this commutation identity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator

How to prove this identity?
$$[(\overrightarrow{\sigma}\cdot\overrightarrow{r}),(\overrightarrow{\sigma}\cdot\overrightarrow{p})]=\frac{4i}{\hbar}\overrightarrow{L}\cdot\overrightarrow{S}+3i\hbar$$
I tried somethings but i just ended up lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need:

- Commutation relation of $\mathbf r,\mathbf p$, given by $[r_i,p_j]=i\hbar\delta_{ij}$
  where $\delta_{ij}$ is Kronecker's delta
- The following identity for the Pauli matrices
  $$\sigma_i\sigma_j=\delta_{ij}+i\epsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k$$
  where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol.

The rest is just willful work.